# redefinition of default parameter : parameter 2

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a class header file like below:

TString.h

```
namespace Utils
{
class UTILS_API TString  
{
public:
    TString(const TString& tstr);
    TString(LPCTSTR tstr = NULL, int len = -1);
    TString(LPCSTR str, int len = -1);
    ..........................
 }
```

Its giving error: error C2548: 'Utils::TString::TString' : missing default parameter for parameter 2

I think, I can assign default values in the header file and this is correct; then why this error is showing?

How can I clear this error?

Comment: First, what character set are you compiling for?  If it's MBCS or "None", your code will not compile, since `LPCSTR == LPCTSTR`.  If you want to distinguish between narrow and wide strings, you should make one `LPCWSTR` and the other `LPCSTR`.

Answer (score 4):

`LPCTSTR` is a `const TCHAR` string.  A `TCHAR` can either be a `char` or `wchar_t`.

`LPCSTR` is a `const char` string.

So if `TCHAR` is being resolved to a `char` then `LPCTSTR` and `LPCSTR` are the same type and now you have two functions with the exact same types but different default parameters which is not allowed